# working out how long a value has been in the mysql database

Tags: mysql

is there a query that i could use to work out the time difference between when a value is 1st seen and when the query is run where the time difference between a value is no more than half hour? so if for example there is data like below

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID| DATE             | TIME                 |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 18/07/2018       | 10:33:15              |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 18/07/2018       | 10:53:15              |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 18/07/2018       | 11:03:15              |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 18/07/2018       | 11:53:15              |
--------------------------------------------------
```

the outcome would be

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID|    DATE             | TimePresent           |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 |    18/07/2018       | 10:33:15              |
--------------------------------------------------
```

so it works out the time between 10:33 and 11:10 as the data inputted is no more than 30 minutes apart and secludes 11:53 because its more than 30 minutes away from the last input at 11:03 
I hope im making sense

the results im after are something like this.

```
--------------------------------------------
| ID| DATE             | TimePresent       |
--------------------------------------------
| 1 | 18/07/2018       | 00.45             |
--------------------------------------------
| 2 | 18/07/2018       | 24:00             |
--------------------------------------------
| 3 | 18/07/2018       | 45:00             |
--------------------------------------------
| 4 | 18/07/2018       | 72:15             |
--------------------------------------------------
```

e.g.

```
SELECT ID,
       Avg(id 1st seen, now) AS timepresent
FROM database.table
WHERE TIME BETWEEN value inputs < now() - interval 30 MINUTE
```

if there isn't a way to determine the time between value inputs then would there be a way to do it as below?

```
SELECT ID,
       Avg(id 1st seen, now) AS timepresent
FROM database.table
WHERE date = CURDATE()
GROUP BY ID
```

[image: Data]

Comment: is there a timestamp column?

Comment: there is a time column which adds the time when the value is inputted into the database

Comment: show the table structure, some sample data and expected results based on the sample data please

Comment: I have added A picture of example data if you would like it in text form i will Edit the question.

Comment: Sorry I assumed you were using mssql. I will redo the answer

Comment: @RyanGadsdon i am using mysql

Comment: @AvalonParkes-barton Hey, please see my revised version for mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see link below

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/486850/81

```
CREATE TABLE Test (

id int primary key,
Present varchar(10),
Date date,
Time time
);

INSERT INTO Test (id, Present, Date, Time)
Values (1, 'Present', '2018-07-18', '10:13:55' ),
(2, 'Present', '2018-07-18', '10:10:55' );
```

Query for minutes:

```
SELECT 
id,
Present,
Date,
Time,
Current_Time as CurrentTime,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS DifferenceMins
FROM Test
```

Query for hh:mm:ss

```
SELECT 
id,
Present,
Date,
Time,
Current_Time as CurrentTime,
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),time)) AS 
TimeDifference
FROM Test
```

Result:

```
| id | Present |       Date |     Time | CurrentTime | DifferenceMins |
|----|---------|------------|----------|-------------|----------------|
|  1 | Present | 2018-07-18 | 10:13:55 |    13:33:28 |            199 |
|  2 | Present | 2018-07-18 | 10:10:55 |    13:33:28 |            202 |
```

I think this is the rough logic you're looking for. You can then add where to filter for 30 mins etc. Time is the time the data was added and then current time is the exact time the query is executed.

Comment: @AvalonParkes-barton 2 secs

Comment: that works spot on is there a way to have it as hour+ minutes rather than just minutes?

Comment: @AvalonParkes-barton use this instead    SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),time)) AS TimeDifference